# for i in range para "intercalar" frases

Tags: python

Tengo que imprimir las siguientes frases de esta manera:

```
J1 obtuvo Q + K = 25
J2 obtuvo A - K = -12
J1 gana la ronda

J1 obtuvo 2 + A = 3
J2 obtuvo 2 - 6 = -4
J1 gana la ronda

J1 obtuvo 4 + 6 = 10
J2 obtuvo 8 - 10 = -2
J1 gana la ronda
```

Sin embargo las tengo así:

```
J1 obtuvo Q + K = 25
J1 obtuvo 2 + A = 3
J1 obtuvo 4 + 6 = 10
J1 obtuvo 4 + 7 = 11
J1 obtuvo K + 5 = 18
J2 obtuvo A - K = -12
J2 obtuvo 2 - 6 = -4
J2 obtuvo 8 - 10 = -2
J2 obtuvo 5 - 6 = -1
J2 obtuvo 3 - 8 = -5
```

Además hay que agregarle quién ganó en cada "juego" (gana el con el número mayor).
Sé que se puede hacer con un for i in range, pero no me está funcionando, intenté esto:

```
for i in range(0,10,4):
```

(Por si acaso son cartas así que A,J,Q y K tienen los valores de 1,11,12 y 13, respectivamente)

Comment: Faltaría algo más de contexto  para poder dar una respuesta adecuada ¿generas las cartas de cada jugador y resuelves quién gana  en el mismo ciclo que imprime o las tienes en contenedores como listas con todas las rondas ya generadas antes de imprimir?

Comment: @FJSevilla Tengo todas las cartas en una lista con las rondas ya generadas antes de imprimir.

Comment: ¿Una lista para cada jugador? Seria muy bueno que agregaras a la pregunta el ejemplo de las dos listas (o la lista, si tienes solo una con las rondas y las cartas de ambos jugadores) para esa salida, la forma de proceder depende directamente de la estructura de éstos datos.